# How can I start a new glutMainLoop() after exiting one in OpenGL with Perl?

Tags: perl, opengl, glut

I've written a Perl script using [OpenGL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OpenGL). It calls `glutMainLoop()` to let the user view some stuff, then the user closes the window but I want to let him continue using the script and reopening a new window and seeing some other stuff. Is that possible? I've found that it is possible to execute this instruction:

```
glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);
```

to return to the code after the window is closed. But then if I call again a `glut*` function it tells me that I can't call it without calling `glutInit` and if I call `glutInit` it tells me that I can't just call it again! Is there some trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  [OpenGL says](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html): "This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program."

Sounds like you need to use OpenGL without GLUT, or at least without `glutMainLoop`.  Or maybe you can use an idle callback or timer callback to continue your windowless processing from inside the main loop.

Comment: I see, problably it's better to go away from GLUT then. I'll try SDL.

Comment: Also worth considering using `glutMainLoopEvent()` if using FreeGLUT.